# Converting variable dimension to standard dimension

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-structures

In ceramic company there standard size but customer request is not same as standard so , we have to customize customer request to standard.

Example available size is (length, width, thickness) 120 * 30 * 3 : 140, 30, 2 : 100, 20, 2.1

If the customer request is 115, 25, 3 we will select from available sizes which is 120 * 30 * 3.

If customer request is 250 * 30 * 3 we will select the optimal size even its possible to combine available sizes.

Please I need your support.

Comment: So how do you recieve your data from user?A textfield?Why dont you use a dropdown?

Comment: Using text field field, customer can request any size...

Comment: So if you want your customers send their requests in any size,why do you want to find the requested size class?

Answer (score 0):

A very very simple algorithm would be to firstly find all tiles that would fit the requirement. i.e.

**Requested tile = RT** width=120; length=100; thickness = 5; i.e
1) **RT** = (120,100,5)

**Available tiles = AT** :
1) **AT** = (150,120,10)
2) **AT** = (120,120,5)
3) **AT** = (100,110,10)

Loop through all available tiles and make sure the dimensions for the requested tile fits
i.e.
**`RT.width <= AT.width AND RT.length <= AT.length AND RT.thickness <= AT.thickness`**

Now you may end up with more than 1 available tile. In this case (1) and (2).
A crude way to select the most fitting tile is find the least difference in each dimension and adding it e.g.

```
1) (150,120,10) - (120,100,5) = (30,20,5) => 30 + 20 + 5 = 55   
2) (120,120,5) - (120,100,5) = (0,20,0) => 0 + 20 + 0 = 20
```

The one with the smallest value is the best fit. Note this is a very crude solution.

Comment: Dear, this works for if RT less than how about if RT greater than AT

Comment: If RT is greater than AT then in theory the store doesn't have a tile with a dimension that fits or is bigger than the required tile. Oh wait... I didn't read the line about putting tiles together. But this should be easy enough to sort out. Then simply find the smallest tile (smallest area) with a side that makes up the required side

Comment: Really thank you, but my question is if RT is greater than AT u can merge more than two AT